# Different uses of noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

In the book *The C++ Programming Language* it is written that you can declare a function to be conditionally `noexcept`. For example:

```
template<typename T>
void my_fct(T& x) noexcept(std::is_pod<T>::value);
```

`noexcept` takes a predicate that must be a constant expression (in the example `std::is_pod<T>::value`).

However, in the book it is also written:

> The `noexcept()` operator takes an expression as its argument and
>   returns `true` if the compiler knows that it cannot throw and `false`
>   otherwise.

Taking this into account, consider:

```
constexpr bool f() { return true; }

void g() noexcept(f())
{
    f();
}
```

Is `g()` marked as `noexcept` or not? I see two possibilities:

1. The call `f()` is evaluated at compile-time because it is marked `constexpr`, it returns `true` and as a result `g()` is marked `noexcept`.
2. The compiler cannot determine that `f()` cannot throw an exception because `f()` is not marked `noexcept`. As a result `g()` is not marked `noexcept`.

Which one does happen? How can I select one or other behavior for `noexcept`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which one does happen?

1.

> How can I select one or other behavior for noexcept?

Using context. Function declaration is the only context where the predicate meaning is used.

If you want to use the noexcept operator within the noexcept predicate, you need to write:

```
void g() noexcept(noexcept(f()))
```

Answer (score 5):

The language grammar allows only the `noexcept` *specifier* to appear in that position.

Therefore your first point is correct. `g()` will be marked `noexcept`, because `f()` returns `true`.

The `noexcept` *operator* must appear in an expression. The `noexcept` specifier takes an expression as argument, so if one wants to have a function be `noexcept` depending on whether a certain expression is `noexcept`, one has to write:

```
void g() noexcept(noexcept(f()))
{
    f();
}
```

which will behave according to your second point.

Comment: Don't forget the ever-useless `g() noexcept(noexcept(noexcept(f()))`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0facbfbe71e7191c (is checking if `f()` is noexcept a noexcept operation?  If so, I am noexcept)